# How to solve SSRS "Could not load Authorization extension" exception?

Tags: c#, reporting-services, ssrs-2012

I am trying to implement custom authentication for SSRS 2014, but I can't get it to work.

What I do have working is the login page. I can see the login page and I can (kind of) succesfully login. When I enter the wrong credentials, it stays on the login page. When I enter valid credentials I am redirected to `/Reports/Pages/Folder.aspx` or in case of the report server to `/`.

But then I see an Exception in the log: `Could not load Authorization extension`:

The logfile:

```
ui!ReportServer_0-1!4f4!08/06/2016-09:16:40:: e ERROR: Software Usage Metrics initialize failed
library!ReportServer_0-1!4f4!08/06/2016-09:16:41:: e ERROR: Throwing Microsoft.ReportingServices.Diagnostics.Utilities.ServerConfigurationErrorException: Could not load Authorization extension, Microsoft.ReportingServices.Diagnostics.Utilities.ServerConfigurationErrorException: The report server has encountered a configuration error. ;
appdomainmanager!ReportManager_0-2!1654!08/06/2016-09:16:43:: i INFO: RS authentication mode is 16; effective ASP.NET authentication mode is Forms. vdir=/Reports.
ui!ReportManager_0-2!1654!08/06/2016-09:16:43:: e ERROR: Software Usage Metrics initialize failed
library!ReportServer_0-1!3468!08/06/2016-09:16:48:: i INFO: Call to GetPermissionsAction(/).
library!ReportServer_0-1!3468!08/06/2016-09:16:48:: e ERROR: Throwing Microsoft.ReportingServices.Diagnostics.Utilities.ServerConfigurationErrorException: Could not load Authorization extension, Microsoft.ReportingServices.Diagnostics.Utilities.ServerConfigurationErrorException: The report server has encountered a configuration error. ;
ui!ReportManager_0-2!1654!08/06/2016-09:16:48:: e ERROR: System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapException: System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapException: The report server has encountered a configuration error.  ---> Microsoft.ReportingServices.Diagnostics.Utilities.ServerConfigurationErrorException: The report server has encountered a configuration error. 
   at Microsoft.ReportingServices.Library.ReportingService2005Impl.GetPermissions(String Item, String[]& Permissions)
   at Microsoft.ReportingServices.WebServer.ReportingService2010.GetPermissions(String ItemPath, String[]& Permissions)
   at System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapHttpClientProtocol.ReadResponse(SoapClientMessage message, WebResponse response, Stream responseStream, Boolean asyncCall)
   at System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapHttpClientProtocol.Invoke(String methodName, Object[] parameters)
   at Microsoft.SqlServer.ReportingServices2010.ReportingService2010.GetPermissions(String ItemPath)
   at Microsoft.SqlServer.ReportingServices2010.RSConnection2010.<>c__DisplayClass3e.<GetPermissions>b__3d()
   at Microsoft.SqlServer.ReportingServices2010.RSConnection2010.SoapMethodWrapper`1.ExecuteMethod(Boolean setConnectionProtocol)
   at Microsoft.SqlServer.ReportingServices2010.RSConnection2010.SoapMethodWrapper`1.ExecuteMethod()
   at Microsoft.SqlServer.ReportingServices2010.RSConnection2010.GetPermissions(String itemPath)
   at Microsoft.ReportingServices.UI.Permissions.GetPermissions()
   at Microsoft.ReportingServices.UI.Permissions.CurrentUser(String itemPath)
   at Microsoft.ReportingServices.UI.ReportingPage.get_RSUser()
   at Microsoft.ReportingServices.UI.FolderPage.Page_Init(Object sender, EventArgs e)
   at System.EventHandler.Invoke(Object sender, EventArgs e)
   at System.Web.UI.Control.OnInit(EventArgs e)
   at System.Web.UI.Page.OnInit(EventArgs e)
   at System.Web.UI.Control.InitRecursive(Control namingContainer)
   at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)
library!ReportServer_0-1!954!08/06/2016-09:16:48:: i INFO: Call to GetSystemPermissionsAction().
library!ReportServer_0-1!954!08/06/2016-09:16:48:: e ERROR: Throwing Microsoft.ReportingServices.Diagnostics.Utilities.ServerConfigurationErrorException: Could not load Authorization extension, Microsoft.ReportingServices.Diagnostics.Utilities.ServerConfigurationErrorException: The report server has encountered a configuration error. ;
ui!ReportManager_0-2!1654!08/06/2016-09:16:48:: e ERROR: HTTP status code --> 200
-------Details--------
System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapException: System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapException: The report server has encountered a configuration error.  ---> Microsoft.ReportingServices.Diagnostics.Utilities.ServerConfigurationErrorException: The report server has encountered a configuration error. 
   at Microsoft.ReportingServices.Library.ReportingService2005Impl.GetPermissions(String Item, String[]& Permissions)
   at Microsoft.ReportingServices.WebServer.ReportingService2010.GetPermissions(String ItemPath, String[]& Permissions)

   at System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapHttpClientProtocol.ReadResponse(SoapClientMessage message, WebResponse response, Stream responseStream, Boolean asyncCall)

   at System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapHttpClientProtocol.Invoke(String methodName, Object[] parameters)

   at Microsoft.SqlServer.ReportingServices2010.ReportingService2010.GetPermissions(String ItemPath)

   at Microsoft.SqlServer.ReportingServices2010.RSConnection2010.<>c__DisplayClass3e.<GetPermissions>b__3d()

   at Microsoft.SqlServer.ReportingServices2010.RSConnection2010.SoapMethodWrapper`1.ExecuteMethod(Boolean setConnectionProtocol)

   at Microsoft.SqlServer.ReportingServices2010.RSConnection2010.SoapMethodWrapper`1.ExecuteMethod()

   at Microsoft.SqlServer.ReportingServices2010.RSConnection2010.GetPermissions(String itemPath)

   at Microsoft.ReportingServices.UI.Permissions.GetPermissions()

   at Microsoft.ReportingServices.UI.Permissions.CurrentUser(String itemPath)

   at Microsoft.ReportingServices.UI.ReportingPage.get_RSUser()

   at Microsoft.ReportingServices.UI.FolderPage.Page_Init(Object sender, EventArgs e)

   at System.EventHandler.Invoke(Object sender, EventArgs e)

   at System.Web.UI.Control.OnInit(EventArgs e)

   at System.Web.UI.Page.OnInit(EventArgs e)

   at System.Web.UI.Control.InitRecursive(Control namingContainer)

   at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)
library!ReportServer_0-1!3468!08/06/2016-09:16:48:: i INFO: Call to GetSystemPropertiesAction().
ui!ReportManager_0-2!1654!08/06/2016-09:16:49:: e ERROR: System.Threading.ThreadAbortException: Thread was being aborted.
   at System.Threading.Thread.AbortInternal()
   at System.Threading.Thread.Abort(Object stateInfo)
   at System.Web.HttpResponse.End()
   at Microsoft.ReportingServices.UI.ReportingPage.ShowErrorPage(String errMsg)
```

rsreportserver.config:

```
<Authentication>
    <AuthenticationTypes>
        <Custom />
    </AuthenticationTypes>
    <EnableAuthPersistence>true</EnableAuthPersistence>
    <RSWindowsExtendedProtectionLevel>Off</RSWindowsExtendedProtectionLevel>
    <RSWindowsExtendedProtectionScenario>Proxy</RSWindowsExtendedProtectionScenario>
</Authentication>

...

<UI>
    <CustomAuthenticationUI>
        <loginUrl>/Logon.aspx</loginUrl>
        <UseSSL>False</UseSSL>
        <PassThroughCookies>
            <PassThroughCookie>sqlAuthCookie</PassThroughCookie>
        </PassThroughCookies>
    </CustomAuthenticationUI>
    <ReportServerUrl>http://localhost/ReportServer</ReportServerUrl>
</UI>

...

<!-- Under Extensions tag -->
<Security>
    <Extension Name="Forms" Type="SsrsCustomAuthWeb.SsrsAuth.SsrsCustomAuthentication, SsrsCustomAuthWeb" >
        <Configuration>
            <AdminConfiguration>
                <UserName>Martijn</UserName>
            </AdminConfiguration>
        </Configuration>
    </Extension>
</Security>
<Authentication>
    <Extension Name="Forms" Type="SsrsCustomAuthWeb.SsrsAuth.SsrsCustomAuthentication, SsrsCustomAuthWeb"/>
</Authentication>
```

web.config of the ReportServer:

```
 <authentication mode="Forms">
  <forms loginUrl="Logon.aspx" name="sqlAuthCookie" timeout="60" path="/"/>
</authentication>
<authorization> 
    <deny users="?" />
</authorization>
```

web.config of the ReportManager

```
 <authentication mode="Forms">
</authentication>
```

SsrsCustomAuthentication.cs

```
public class SsrsCustomAuthentication : IAuthenticationExtension
{
    public string LocalizedName
    {
        get
        {
            return null;
        }
    }

    public void GetUserInfo(out IIdentity userIdentity, out IntPtr userId)
    {
        userIdentity = HttpContext.Current.User.Identity;
        userId = IntPtr.Zero;
    }

    public bool IsValidPrincipalName(string principalName)
    {
        return true;
    }

    public bool LogonUser(string userName, string password, string authority)
    {
        if (userName == "Martijn")
            return true;

        return false;
    }

    public void SetConfiguration(string configuration)
    {

    }
}
```

Authorization.cs

```
public class Authorization : IAuthorizationExtension
{
    private static string m_adminUserName;
    static Authorization()
    {
        InitializeMaps();
    }

    public byte[] CreateSecurityDescriptor(AceCollection acl, SecurityItemType itemType, out string stringSecDesc)
    {
        // Creates a memory stream and serializes the ACL for storage.
        BinaryFormatter bf = new BinaryFormatter();
        using (MemoryStream result = new MemoryStream())
        {
            bf.Serialize(result, acl);
            stringSecDesc = null;
            return result.GetBuffer();
        }
    }

    public bool CheckAccess(string userName,IntPtr userToken,byte[] secDesc, ModelItemOperation modelItemOperation)
    {
        if (0 == String.Compare(userName, m_adminUserName, true,CultureInfo.CurrentCulture))
            return true;

        AceCollection acl = DeserializeAcl(secDesc);
        foreach (AceStruct ace in acl)
        {
            if (0 == String.Compare(userName, ace.PrincipalName, true,CultureInfo.CurrentCulture))
            {
                foreach (ModelItemOperation aclOperation in ace.ModelItemOperations)
                {
                    if (aclOperation == modelItemOperation)
                        return true;
                }
            }
        }

        return false;
    }

    public bool CheckAccess( string userName,IntPtr userToken, byte[] secDesc,ModelOperation modelOperation)
    {
        if (0 == String.Compare(userName, m_adminUserName, true, CultureInfo.CurrentCulture))
            return true;

        AceCollection acl = DeserializeAcl(secDesc);
        foreach (AceStruct ace in acl)
        {
            if (0 == String.Compare(userName, ace.PrincipalName, true, CultureInfo.CurrentCulture))
            {
                foreach (ModelOperation aclOperation in ace.ModelOperations)
                {
                    if (aclOperation == modelOperation)
                        return true;
                }
            }
        }

        return false;
    }

    public bool CheckAccess(string userName,IntPtr userToken,byte[] secDesc,CatalogOperation requiredOperation)
    {
        if (0 == String.Compare(userName, m_adminUserName, true, CultureInfo.CurrentCulture))
            return true;

        AceCollection acl = DeserializeAcl(secDesc);
        foreach (AceStruct ace in acl)
        {
            if (0 == String.Compare(userName, ace.PrincipalName, true,CultureInfo.CurrentCulture))
            {
                foreach (CatalogOperation aclOperation in ace.CatalogOperations)
                {
                    if (aclOperation == requiredOperation)
                        return true;
                }
            }
        }

        return false;
    }

    public bool CheckAccess(string userName,IntPtr userToken, byte[] secDesc,CatalogOperation[] requiredOperations)
    {
        foreach (CatalogOperation operation in requiredOperations)
        {
            if (!CheckAccess(userName, userToken, secDesc, operation))
                return false;
        }
        return true;
    }

    public bool CheckAccess(string userName, IntPtr userToken,byte[] secDesc,ReportOperation requiredOperation)
    {
        // If the user is the administrator, allow unrestricted access.
        if (0 == String.Compare(userName, m_adminUserName, true,CultureInfo.CurrentCulture))
            return true;

        AceCollection acl = DeserializeAcl(secDesc);
        foreach (AceStruct ace in acl)
        {
            if (0 == String.Compare(userName, ace.PrincipalName, true,CultureInfo.CurrentCulture))
            {
                foreach (ReportOperation aclOperation in ace.ReportOperations)
                {
                    if (aclOperation == requiredOperation)
                        return true;
                }
            }
        }
        return false;
    }

    public bool CheckAccess(string userName,IntPtr userToken,byte[] secDesc,FolderOperation requiredOperation)
    {
        // If the user is the administrator, allow unrestricted access.
        if (0 == String.Compare(userName, m_adminUserName, true,CultureInfo.CurrentCulture))
            return true;

        AceCollection acl = DeserializeAcl(secDesc);
        foreach (AceStruct ace in acl)
        {
            if (0 == String.Compare(userName, ace.PrincipalName, true, CultureInfo.CurrentCulture))
            {
                foreach (FolderOperation aclOperation in ace.FolderOperations)
                {
                    if (aclOperation == requiredOperation)
                        return true;
                }
            }
        }

        return false;
    }

    public bool CheckAccess(string userName, IntPtr userToken,  byte[] secDesc, FolderOperation[] requiredOperations)
    {
        foreach (FolderOperation operation in requiredOperations)
        {
            if (!CheckAccess(userName, userToken, secDesc, operation))
                return false;
        }
        return true;
    }

    public bool CheckAccess( string userName,IntPtr userToken,  byte[] secDesc, ResourceOperation requiredOperation)
    {
        // If the user is the administrator, allow unrestricted access.
        if (0 == String.Compare(userName, m_adminUserName, true,  CultureInfo.CurrentCulture))
            return true;

        AceCollection acl = DeserializeAcl(secDesc);
        foreach (AceStruct ace in acl)
        {
            if (0 == String.Compare(userName, ace.PrincipalName, true, CultureInfo.CurrentCulture))
            {
                foreach (ResourceOperation aclOperation in ace.ResourceOperations)
                {
                    if (aclOperation == requiredOperation)
                        return true;
                }
            }
        }

        return false;
    }

    public bool CheckAccess(string userName, IntPtr userToken,byte[] secDesc, ResourceOperation[] requiredOperations)
    {
        // If the user is the administrator, allow unrestricted access.
        if (0 == String.Compare(userName, m_adminUserName, true, CultureInfo.CurrentCulture))
            return true;

        foreach (ResourceOperation operation in requiredOperations)
        {
            if (!CheckAccess(userName, userToken, secDesc, operation))
                return false;
        }
        return true;
    }

    public bool CheckAccess( string userName, IntPtr userToken, byte[] secDesc, DatasourceOperation requiredOperation)
    {
        // If the user is the administrator, allow unrestricted access.
        if (0 == String.Compare(userName, m_adminUserName, true, CultureInfo.CurrentCulture))
            return true;

        AceCollection acl = DeserializeAcl(secDesc);
        foreach (AceStruct ace in acl)
        {
            if (0 == String.Compare(userName, ace.PrincipalName, true,CultureInfo.CurrentCulture))
            {
                foreach (DatasourceOperation aclOperation in ace.DatasourceOperations)
                {
                    if (aclOperation == requiredOperation)
                        return true;
                }
            }
        }

        return false;
    }

    public StringCollection GetPermissions(string userName, IntPtr userToken,SecurityItemType itemType, byte[] secDesc)
    {
        StringCollection permissions = new StringCollection();
        if (0 == String.Compare(userName, m_adminUserName, true,CultureInfo.CurrentCulture))
        {
            foreach (CatalogOperation oper in m_CatOperNames.Keys)
            {
                if (!permissions.Contains((string)m_CatOperNames[oper]))
                    permissions.Add((string)m_CatOperNames[oper]);
            }
            foreach (ModelItemOperation oper in m_ModelItemOperNames.Keys)
            {
                if (!permissions.Contains((string)m_ModelItemOperNames[oper]))
                    permissions.Add((string)m_ModelItemOperNames[oper]);
            }
            foreach (ModelOperation oper in m_ModelOperNames.Keys)
            {
                if (!permissions.Contains((string)m_ModelOperNames[oper]))
                    permissions.Add((string)m_ModelOperNames[oper]);
            }
            foreach (CatalogOperation oper in m_CatOperNames.Keys)
            {
                if (!permissions.Contains((string)m_CatOperNames[oper]))
                    permissions.Add((string)m_CatOperNames[oper]);
            }
            foreach (ReportOperation oper in m_RptOperNames.Keys)
            {
                if (!permissions.Contains((string)m_RptOperNames[oper]))
                    permissions.Add((string)m_RptOperNames[oper]);
            }
            foreach (FolderOperation oper in m_FldOperNames.Keys)
            {
                if (!permissions.Contains((string)m_FldOperNames[oper]))
                    permissions.Add((string)m_FldOperNames[oper]);
            }
            foreach (ResourceOperation oper in m_ResOperNames.Keys)
            {
                if (!permissions.Contains((string)m_ResOperNames[oper]))
                    permissions.Add((string)m_ResOperNames[oper]);
            }
            foreach (DatasourceOperation oper in m_DSOperNames.Keys)
            {
                if (!permissions.Contains((string)m_DSOperNames[oper]))
                    permissions.Add((string)m_DSOperNames[oper]);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            AceCollection acl = DeserializeAcl(secDesc);
            foreach (AceStruct ace in acl)
            {
                if (0 == String.Compare(userName, ace.PrincipalName, true, CultureInfo.CurrentCulture))
                {
                    foreach (ModelItemOperation aclOperation in ace.ModelItemOperations)
                    {
                        if (!permissions.Contains((string)m_ModelItemOperNames[aclOperation]))
                            permissions.Add((string)m_ModelItemOperNames[aclOperation]);
                    }
                    foreach (ModelOperation aclOperation in ace.ModelOperations)
                    {
                        if (!permissions.Contains((string)m_ModelOperNames[aclOperation]))
                            permissions.Add((string)m_ModelOperNames[aclOperation]);
                    }
                    foreach (CatalogOperation aclOperation in ace.CatalogOperations)
                    {
                        if (!permissions.Contains((string)m_CatOperNames[aclOperation]))
                            permissions.Add((string)m_CatOperNames[aclOperation]);
                    }
                    foreach (ReportOperation aclOperation in ace.ReportOperations)
                    {
                        if (!permissions.Contains((string)m_RptOperNames[aclOperation]))
                            permissions.Add((string)m_RptOperNames[aclOperation]);
                    }
                    foreach (FolderOperation aclOperation in ace.FolderOperations)
                    {
                        if (!permissions.Contains((string)m_FldOperNames[aclOperation]))
                            permissions.Add((string)m_FldOperNames[aclOperation]);
                    }
                    foreach (ResourceOperation aclOperation in ace.ResourceOperations)
                    {
                        if (!permissions.Contains((string)m_ResOperNames[aclOperation]))
                            permissions.Add((string)m_ResOperNames[aclOperation]);
                    }
                    foreach (DatasourceOperation aclOperation in ace.DatasourceOperations)
                    {
                        if (!permissions.Contains((string)m_DSOperNames[aclOperation]))
                            permissions.Add((string)m_DSOperNames[aclOperation]);
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        return permissions;
    }

    private AceCollection DeserializeAcl(byte[] secDesc)
    {
        AceCollection acl = new AceCollection();
        if (secDesc != null)
        {
            BinaryFormatter bf = new BinaryFormatter();
            using (MemoryStream sdStream = new MemoryStream(secDesc))
            {
                acl = (AceCollection)bf.Deserialize(sdStream);
            }
        }
        return acl;
    }

    private static Hashtable m_ModelItemOperNames;
    private static Hashtable m_ModelOperNames;
    private static Hashtable m_CatOperNames;
    private static Hashtable m_FldOperNames;
    private static Hashtable m_RptOperNames;
    private static Hashtable m_ResOperNames;
    private static Hashtable m_DSOperNames;

    private const int NrRptOperations = 27;
    private const int NrFldOperations = 10;
    private const int NrResOperations = 7;
    private const int NrDSOperations = 7;
    private const int NrCatOperations = 16;
    private const int NrModelOperations = 11;
    private const int NrModelItemOperations = 1;

   private static void InitializeMaps()
    {
        // Perform initialization of some hash maps
    }

   public void SetConfiguration(string configuration)
    {
        XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
        doc.LoadXml(configuration);
        if (doc.DocumentElement.Name == "AdminConfiguration")
        {
            foreach (XmlNode child in doc.DocumentElement.ChildNodes)
            {
                if (child.Name == "UserName")
                {
                    m_adminUserName = child.InnerText;
                }
                else
                {
                    throw new Exception(string.Format(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, "Unrecognized configuration element."));
                }
            }
        }
        else
            throw new Exception(string.Format(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, "Root element is not \"AdminConfiguration\" in config data."));
    }

     public string LocalizedName
    {
        get
        {
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

I finally figured it out. In the end it turned out I made a very subtle configuration error in rsreportserver.config:

The type specified in the `Security` tag needs to be the type of the class that implements the `IAuthorizationExtension` interface.

The type specified in the `Extension` tag (under the `Authentication` tag) is the name of the class that implements the `IAuthenticationExtension` interface. And here I want wrong. Here I had the class that implemented `IAuthorizationExtension`.

Comment: Please tell me you have studied the issue of user authentication for SSRS 2014 on ASP.NET MVC (5 or 6) using ASP.NET Identity?
For six months, I'm trying to find information and to no avail :(